# Sending a JavaScript object to an API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to send this data to an API:

```
data={
 "to":{name : "to whom"}
};
```

But JavaScript doesn't allow me to do so (note that "name" is a variable). On the other hand it allows me to do as following:

```
data={
  "to" :{"me": "to whom"}
};
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: There's no array in this question, just objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES5 doesn't natively allow you to do this. you'd need to create the inner hash as a variable and use that.

```
var address = {};
address[name] = 'to whom';

var data = {
  to: address
};
```

If you're using ES6 syntax, you can add brackets in the declaration

```
var data = {
  to: { [name]: 'to whom' }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript `{name : "to whom"}` and `{"name" : "to whom"}` is exactly the same. What you are looking for are [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
var data = {
    "to": {[name]: "to whom"}
};
```

This syntax is supported in node v6.0.